# How to enable matplotlib blitting to create fast realtime graph in jupyterlab?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, real-time, jupyter-lab

I have the following code in jupyterlab, which updates a graph in realtime when I move a slider. If I disable blitting it updates, although at a very slow framerate (1 fps). If I enable blitting, it doesn't update at all - any idea why? The code uses the ipympl library to allow realtime update of matplotlib graphs in jupyterlab.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from itertools import count
from ipywidgets import Button, Layout

# next line enables ipympl
%matplotlib widget 


blit = True # False works, True doesn't.

plt.close('all')
plt.ioff()

output = widgets.Output(layout={'width': '700px', 'height': '300px'})
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(10, 8), sharex=True)
fig.canvas.header_visible = False
fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False


for i in range(3):    
    axs[i,0].set_ylim(-1.5,1.5)
    axs[i,0].set_xlim(0,20)
    
# index giver
x_value = count()

# expanding dataset
x, y = [], []

# initialise dummy data
[x.append(next(x_value)) for i in range(2)]
[y.append([1]*3) for i in range(2)]

# setup desired and actual angle plots
col_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
ax_df = pd.DataFrame(index=x,columns=col_names, data=y).plot(subplots=True, ax=axs[:,0])

if blit:
    bgs = []
    for ax in ax_df:
        # cache the background
        ax_background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)
        bgs.append(ax_background)
    
    fig.canvas.draw()  # initial draw required

# monitor framerate
t_start = time.time()   

# event handler
def on_value_changed(change):    
    with output:    
        next_x = next(x_value) # generate next x axis value
        x.append(next_x)
        y.append([change.new]*3) 

        for i in range(3):            
            if blit:              
                # update data
                line = ax_df[i].get_lines()[0]
                line.set_data(x, pd.DataFrame(y).iloc[:,i])
                
                # restore background
                fig.canvas.restore_region(bgs[i])
                
                # redraw just the points
                ax_df[i].draw_artist(line)

                # fill in the axes rectangle
                fig.canvas.blit(ax_df[i].bbox)
                
            else:
                # update data
                ax_df[i].get_lines()[0].set_data(x, pd.DataFrame(y).iloc[:,i])

                # rescale view
                ax_df[i].autoscale_view(None,'x',None)
                ax_df[i].relim()
            
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        
        if not blit:
            fig.canvas.draw() # this slows down framerate, not required for blit

        print(f"FPS: {round(next_x/(time.time() - t_start),2)}", end=", ")

sliders = []
int_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(description="test", 
                                 min=-1, max=1, 
                                 value = 0, continuous_update=True,
                                 orientation="horizontal",                                      
                                 layout=Layout(width="500px", height="20px"))    
int_slider.observe(on_value_changed, names="value")
sliders = widgets.VBox([int_slider, fig.canvas, output])
display(sliders)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to originate from the implementation of matplotlib backend "webagg" used by default in jupyter lab (e.g. when using the magic command `%matplotlib widget`). Meaning the blitting *could* work (I haven't checked) if you were to use another backend (qt or tkinter).

=> See this Github Issue for the whole story : [Support blitting in webagg backend #19059](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/19059)

Until recently (3/12/2020 & matplotlib 3.3), the blitting was not implemented in the file "backend_webagg_core.py" of the matplotlib module.

Less than a week ago, matplotlib developpers have proposed a patch for this functionnality.

If you want to do it on your own because you don't want to wait for a patch that would come in 2021, you need to modify a few lines in the matplotlib module.

> I don't know it this modification would survive a pip update (hopefully not) and I wouldn't recommend it if you don't know what you are doing, since the matplotlib dev team runs several tests to make sure the whole code doesn't break when modifying the module source code.

For this you would need to do modify the class `FigureCanvasWebAggCore` from backend_webagg_core.py:

```
class FigureCanvasWebAggCore(backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg):
    supports_blit = True # instead of False
```

then inside the same class, add the following after the function "draw"

```
def blit(self, bbox=None):
    self._png_is_old = True
    self.manager.refresh_all()
```

you should also modify the following lines ( **-** means delete / **+** means add / no symbol means leave as it is):

```
-               last_buffer = (np.frombuffer(self._last_renderer.buffer_rgba(),
-                                             dtype=np.uint32)
-                               .reshape((renderer.height, renderer.width)))
-               diff = buff != last_buffer
+               diff = buff != self._last_buff
```

same here

```
-            # Swap the renderer frames
-            self._renderer, self._last_renderer = (
-                self._last_renderer, renderer)
+            # store the current buffer so we can compute the next diff
+            np.copyto(self._last_buff, buff)
```

and there

```
-            self._last_renderer = backend_agg.RendererAgg(
-                w, h, self.figure.dpi)
            self._lastKey = key
+            self._last_buff = np.copy(np.frombuffer(
+                self._renderer.buffer_rgba(), dtype=np.uint32
+            ).reshape((self._renderer.height, self._renderer.width)))
```

Have a look this Github Issue for more details:
[Support blitting in webagg backend #19059](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/19059)

---

**A thought about the FPS**

Before changing the core code of matplotlib, I would suggest a few modifications of your example.

1. I would change the way you compute FPS. The formula for computing the time spent to redraw should be imbedded fully within the function that does the drawing.
2. Creating a panda data frame to update y seems a bit slow to me. A numpty array would be sufficient. Then, this array should live outside the for loop.

```
    def on_value_changed(change):    
        # monitor framerate
        t_start = time.time()
        with output:  
            global x,y
            x.append(next_x)
            y.append([change.new]*3) 
            ytmp = np.array(y)
        ...

        print(f"FPS: {round(1/(time.time() - t_start),2)}", end=", ")
```

By performing those modifications, I get FPS output ranging from 4 to 8.

If I use a for loop to update the matplotlib drawing, the FPS goes between 6 and 11 (mostly around 10, 11):

```
class stuff:
    
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.new = x

s = stuff(0)
for i in range(40):
    s.new = np.random.rand()
    on_value_changed(s)
```

Now, to improve this score, we can probably go into the matplotlib code. But it is my beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried adding the patch, and it now updates the graph even when blitting. However, some fragments of the graph remain white (seems like an update error), and the framerate actually drops to about 0.4 fps.

Comment: I have used the patch myself and it also works for me. Have you looked at the github repo ? It could be useful for you to talk with the matplotlib dev team working on the patch. they could guide you better than me on this. If my reply got you moving, maybe you could accept my answer and pursue the quest on github. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I up voted your answer. However, as it didn't fix my issue I cant accept it as the answer at the moment. If I understand the pull request correctly, it seems to enable bitting but does necessarily also address low framerate. The person writing the patch had already reached out to me as I had filed an issue in the ipympl repo a while ago.

Comment: I understand, my answer has not solved the apparently slow FPS you are having. I am bringing some modifications to your example and I have updated my answer. It looks sort of slow indeed, but I don't know if it can go much faster with matplotlib + slider ...